# ASP.NET Identity - extending the _LoginPartial

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-identity

I'm finding this difficult to summarise, hence the poor question name. On my .net web application, which is using Identity, there is a login partial that was auto generated that displays the users 'username' property like so:

```
@Html.ActionLink(User.Identity.GetUserName(), "Index", "Manage", routeValues: null, htmlAttributes: new {title = "Manage"})
```

After profiling the SQL database that is holding the user data, I noticed that this call to GetUserName() doesn't actually make a call to the database to retrieve the name. I am looking to access a navigation property of the 'ApplicationUser' class that holds the url for a thumbnail image I want to be displayed.

However I am hoping I can achieve this without the need to call the database for the URL on every page request. An example of this would be on this site, where your profile image is displayed on every page as part of the layout.

The application user class has this property.

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    public UserProfile Profile { get; set; }
}
```

And the user profile class holds this property.

```
public class UserProfile
{
    [Key, ForeignKey("User")]
    public string UserId { get; set; }
    public ApplicationUser User { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string ThumbnailUrl { get; set; }

    ...
}
```

How can I do this? Or is there a much better way of trying to achieve this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just add them as claims.
When authenticating you should fetch the User from the DB and add all the properties you would need use later on.

Assuming that you are using CreateIdentity when logging in a user, that should return a ClaimsIdentity object.

```
var userIdentity = await userManager.CreateIdentityAsync(user, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
userIdentity.AddClaim(new Claim("Thumbnail", user.ThumbnailUrl));
```

Then you need to create a extension class, let's say IdentityExtensions:

```
public static class IdentityExtensions{
    public static string Thumbnail(this IIdentity identity){
        try{
            return ((ClaimsIdentity) identity).FindFirst("Thumbnail").Value;
        }
         catch(Exception ex){
         // handle any exception the way you need
        }
    }
}
```

Finally, on your views you should be able to use @User.Identity.Thumbnail()

Answer (score 1):

You're right it doesn't make a call... the reason is because it's holding that data in the client's cookies... If it didn't the server would have a meltdown if it had to keep running back and forth to grab such trivial data for large scale systems... so it's cached.

The way it's done in ASP.NET MVC is via the use of the IPrinciple interface... I'll point you in the right direction to learn more about it... 
[CodeProject: How to implement a custom IPrincipal in MVC](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/574576/How-to-implement-a-custom-IPrincipal-in-ASP-NET-MV)

Comment: would adding properties in the form of claims be a good way to handle this? Similar to how this post directs: http://forums.asp.net/t/1957500.aspx?How+to+access+custom+Identity+or+ApplicationUser+properties+

Answer (score -1):

Best thing todo is to create a second table (or add a column to the current table), add a file upload feature to the registration form. When registration is successful add the picture to the db with EntityFramework. Create a page to return the picture by the userid so you can include it in a page somewhere.

you can use this idea

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2013/10/16/customizing-profile-information-in-asp-net-identity-in-vs-2013-templates.aspx

Comment: Do not do this... and the reason you shouldn't do this @Asad Ali is because you're drastically bloating the database by doing so... If you need to display pictures you upload it to a directory, and serve the images from the directory. You've also not read the OP, who is trying to cache the data client side

Comment: @Asad Ali I was looking to store imagery on the file system rather the db because of the bloating issue and a number of other reasons.

Comment: well i know we should'nt do this at certain points but is effective at certain situations - there are different perspectives. But i gave you the link to check how you can customize the profile - not how to store image in db